# Display variable from model in view Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I am trying to display the value of the variable testing (= 55) on the view by means of the use of a view model. Can anybody help?

Class (Calculations.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tool3.Models
{
    public class Calculations
    {
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller (CalculationsController.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using tool3.Models;

namespace tool3.Controllers
{
    public class CalculationsController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var testing = new Calculations() { Amount = 55 };
            return View(testing);
        }
    }
}
```

Viewmodel (EFViewModel.cs):

```
using tool3.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tool3.ViewModel
{
    public class EFViewModel
    {
        public Calculations Calculations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index View (Index.cshtml), I just want to display the number "55" here:

```
@model tool3.ViewModel.EFViewModel

        @Model.Calculations.Amount
```

I get the error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
tool3.ViewModel.EFViewModel.Calculations.get returned null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: var testing = new EFViewModel() { Calculations = new Calculations() { Amount = 55 }};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be passing an instance of **EFViewModel** to the view as the model, since that is the type the view is expecting.

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var testing = new EFViewModel() { Calculations = new Calculations() { Amount = 55 }};
    return View(testing);
}
```